# problems subscribing to turtlebot_node/sensor_state

Tags: python, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to subscribe to turtlebot_node/sensor_state so that I can tell when my Turtlebot has bumped into something and handle it accordingly.  Whenever I try to run it, however, it gives me the error message:

```
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_teleop 
 /bin/turtlebot_teleop_key", line 35, in <module>
     from turtlebot_node.msg import TurtlebotSensorState
 ImportError: No module named turtlebot_node.msg
```

My import statements are as follows:

```
from os import system
import curses
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('turtlebot_teleop')
import rospy
import random
from turtlebot_node.msg import TurtlebotSensorState
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
```

From other examples I can find online, it seems like this should work.  turtlebot_node is definitely running correctly and I have no trouble getting it to move without implementing a bump correction algorithm.  What do you think is wrong?

Thanks,
Matthew

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11997/problems-subscribing-to-turtlebot_node/sensor_state/) by [saltzm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1408/saltzm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How did you install the turtlebot_node package? If it is from source, you need to run "make" to generate the message headers.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-26**:
I recommend using rosmake in your package.  The build system has to generate the message processing code which is failing to import.